# Extend Strapi Social Auth Providers API for React Native

Tags: oauth, strapi

I'm trying to achieve authorization with Strapi with Facebook login in React Native. Using the FB login with fbsdk, I get the user to log in, and on success, pass the credentials to my app. The problem I have now is storing this credentials with Strapi. I could [manually register users](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/authentication.html#registration) with the Strapi API, but then I would have to make up a password for each user and deal with two tokens, one from Facebook and one from Strapi.

I would like to know if there is a way of extending the [current Providers API](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/authentication.html#providers) so I can store the user information from Facebook in Strapi directly without going through this extra step of registering users manually?

I'm using strapi version 3.0.0 beta.

Answer (score 2):

Since Strapi doesn't have Apple social login (which is required in App Store if you add any other social login option), you can do it with Firebase.

We use react-native-firebase library to register users via Twitter, Facebook, Google, and Apple.
We can get a user's token with Firebase and send it to the server instead of using Strapi's JWT.

```
 const token = await auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)
```

Then we set token in axios header to make authenticated requests.

Then slightly customize permission.js function https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/guides/jwt-validation.html#customize-the-jwt-validation-function , adding a layer of firebase validation.
like so:

```
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then(function(decodedToken) {
    let uid = decodedToken.uid;
    // validate 
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error
  });
```

It is also from documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Hope that Strapi will add 100% support for React Native in the future but for now it works.

EDIT:
The path is extensions/users-permissions/config/policies/permissions.js
Here's how you can approach it. Just verify if you have a user in firebase and then fire next() with return

```
    try {
  const { uid } = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
  const user = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.fetch({ uid });

  ctx.state.user = user;

  console.log('Firebase token decode success = ' + uid);
  return await next();
} catch (err) {
  // console.log('Firebase token decode failure');
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by ```// validate ```? I tried using the default authenticate code that strapi uses, but that returns "no user found", even when I hard code the user id

Comment: @AmoghJahagirdar I have edited the answer for you. Hope it gives you better ideas on how to approach it.